# How to execute migration current version using "Symfony doctrine migrations" without any interaction?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

As doctrine migrations help says:

```
Or you can also execute the migration without a warning message which you need to interact with:

      ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
```

I try to run current migration version by command:

```
./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate current --no-interaction
```

Nevertheless, I always get an error:

```
WARNING! You have 1 previously executed migrations in the database that are not registered migrations.
    >> 2020-01-29 13:03:03 (20200129130303)
No migrations to execute.
```

Of course, I clearly understand that "I have 1 previously executed migrations". 
And It is my goal to execute a specific old version without any interaction. How can I achieve it?

Comment: In `migration_versions` table there's a record `20200129130303` - You've previously had that migration and have removed the file, but not the database records. Remove it to make the warning go away. Take it as a lesson to not play with migration classes once they're pushed away from your local machine ;)

Comment: `It is my goal to execute a specific old version without any interaction.` This bit though, unless you've got a script (for deployment, cronjob, etc) setup, is not possible. The command is `bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute 1234567890 -n --up` (or `--down`), replace the number with the datetime stamp of the class name.

Comment: @rkeet I want to use this command in my deploy process via ansible. And the idea is to run the last migrations version in the migration directory. It can be handy when I checkout to a concrete git tag or branch and want to set up my database accordingly to the migrations folder.

Comment: Right, in that case you simply run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n`, what you already did. That command takes all the Migration class files available, checks the number (in the class name) vs the records in `migration_versions` and executes all of the classes that are _not_ in the database. So, if you execute that command (using Ansible) after checking out a specified git commit (or latest "develop" or "master", whatever), then it executes all available to create the "latest available" (within limits of the commit).

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error, that's just warning. It's displayed for the reasons @rkeet mentioned in comment. The command is still executed without interaction.

If you do not want to see any output, you should use `--quiet, -q` flag.

Interaction is when Symfony asks you `Are you sure you want to execute migrations?` (or whatever the messages are), and you answer with either `y` or `n`. This part is omitted with a `--no-interaction` flag.

Comment: As you mentioned, Symfony asks me `Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)?`. When I use `--no-interaction` flag this part is omitted. And the migration command isn't executed! So, I think it isn't good behavior. In my opinion, when I add the flag `--no-interaction` there must be no interaction at all and my migrations must be migrated. But in my case, nothing happens.

Comment: True, because, as you've mentioned: `No migrations to execute.` 
That means all migrations are executed.

Comment: Okay, I understand what do you mean :)
But is there any possibility downgrade my database version if my directory has version less then in migrations_versions table?

Comment: Yes, there is, but that's another question really. To answer your original question again, `doctrine:migration:migrate` command (with any argument) followed with `-q` and `-n` flag will result in a command being run without interaction and without output.

Comment: `But is there any possibility downgrade my database version if my directory has version less then in migrations_versions table? ` @RomanAndreev No - Not in the way you state your question. You state it like : "If I revert a bunch of commits by checking out an earlier version, can I revert the database to that?", the answer is "No." You must (manually!) first revert the database. When you check out (git) an earlier version, you also remove the Migration classes with the down scripts (hence: "You have 1 previously executed migrations in the database [..]"